# Set UEFI boot option from within Windows

Tags: windows-10, uefi

I'm looking to write small batch files which can reboot the computer and set the UEFI boot option to boot from a specific drive. I figured that on some level the UEFI options are exposed to the OS because Windows itself has the ability to change some boot options from it's settings menu. Additionally, software exists to manage this but I'm looking for a programmatic way to do it because I'm trying to incorporate it into a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are resources [listing UEFI calls](http://vzimmer.blogspot.com/2012/12/accessing-uefi-form-operating-system.html) and the [firmware variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724325(v=vs.85).aspx), but if you do not know lower-level languages, Windows does not expose these in the CMD, AFAIK. See [Vincent Zimmer's](http://vzimmer.blogspot.com/2012/12/accessing-uefi-form-operating-system.html) comments.